# Let me skip flags I'm unsure about in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, chat-flags

I clicked on "not sure" on a chat flag because it was in Russian, which I don't speak, then tried to see the next (it indicated that there were 5), but it just showed a "show all" box. When I clicked on that, it took me to [a page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/admin/flagged?show=all) where the only option is "yes" or "no". As I don't speak Russian, I can't see the next flag without doing a likely wrong judgement.

Can this be fixed so that on the page to see all flags you can skip/say you don't know?

Comment: Interesting note: "not sure" actually counts as a fraction of either "yes" or "no" - although I don't remember which. So if enough people click "not sure" it'll either dismiss the flag or delete the message...